# remove columns with NA values from list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix, na

I have a list of matrices, and need to remove columns containing NA values, within each matrix.

I tried to use lapply with !is.na to apply this to all the matrices in the entire list, but what it returns is a list of vectors with NAs excluded, whereas I still want a list of matrices (just without the columns containing NA).

```
> my_list
$mat1
 V1   V2   V3
[1,] 1 5 NA
[1,] 2 6 NA
[1,] 3 7 NA
[1,] 4 8 NA

$mat2
 V1   V2   V3
[1,] 1 NA 9
[1,] 2 NA 10
[1,] 3 NA 11
[1,] 4 NA 12

> lapply(my_list,function(x) x[!is.na(x)])
$mat1
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8

$mat2
 [1]  1  2  3  4  9 10 11 12
```

The output I'm trying to get is this:

```
$mat1
 V1   V2
[1,] 1 5
[1,] 2 6
[1,] 3 7
[1,] 4 8

$mat2
 V1   V3
[1,] 1 9
[1,] 2 10
[1,] 3 11
[1,] 4 12
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] in your question!

Comment: `lapply(my_list,function(x) x[,colSums(is.na(x)) < 1, drop = FALSE])`

Comment: You got downvotes pretty hard because `a.` no example data was given and `b.` [google](https://www.google.de/search?q=remove+columns+matrix+containing+na+in+r&rlz=1C1CHBD_deDE736DE736&oq=remove+columns+matrix+containing+na+in+r&aqs=chrome..69i57.12342j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @RLave complete.cases looks row-wise for `NA`. So not practical here

Comment: thank you for the comment. Did not know that, I see your point.

Comment: For one matrix `apply(is.na(A), 2, any)` gives you the logical index for the columns *with* NA. To remove the columns do: `A[, !apply(is.na(A), 2, any)]`. To do this with a list of matrices do: `lapply(L, function(A) A[, !apply(is.na(A), 2, any)])`

Comment: Thank you, jogo, this solved it. I added an verifiable example to the question now for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one matrix `apply(is.na(mat), 2, any)` gives you the logical index for the columns *with* NA. To remove the columns do:

```
mat[, !apply(is.na(mat), 2, any)]
```

To do this with a list of matrices do:

```
lapply(my_list, function(mat) mat[, !apply(is.na(mat), 2, any)])
```

#### Data:

```
> dput(my_list)
list(structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), .Dim = c(4L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3"
))), structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L), .Dim = c(4L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", 
"V3"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another option is `tidyverse` with `select_if` after converting to `data.frame`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(lst1, ~ .x %>% 
               as.data.frame %>% 
               select_if(~ all(!is.na(.))))
#[[1]]
#  V1 V2
#1  1  5
#2  2  6
#3  3  7
#4  4  8

#[[2]]
#  V1 V3
#1  1  9
#2  2 10
#3  3 11
#4  4 12
```